# How to show a small pop up in custom keyboard app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

My app is a keyboard extension app, i need to show a nice little pop up which says copied once i copy an image to pasteboard.

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(drawView.getImage())
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: "public.png")
```

I need to display a nice pop up which says "copied" after this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this API very useful for me.
https://github.com/devxoul/JLToast

See my updated code here.

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(drawView.getImage())
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: "public.png")


    toastView = JLToastView()
    toastView.textLabel.text = "Copied!"
    self.view.addSubview(toastView)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.toastView.alpha = 0.0
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to temporary pop up for some here is good one library which is written in Objective C you can use in swift also

https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALToastView